# PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio 2019 cannot be installed in Visual

Tags: c#, postsharp

Setting up Postsharp has been a big problem for me. Can't install 2019 VS postsharp?

> PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio 2019 cannot be installed in Visual
> Studio Community 2019 (16.7.1) because the following prerequisites are
> missing: Just In Time debugger (Visual Studio Community 2019) Please
> install individual components or .NET desktop development workload.

postsharp version 6.6.15

Comment: I assume you did what the error message asks, and installed the .NET desktop development workload in the Visual Studio Installer? Did you check that "Just In Time debugger" is installed in the Visual Studio Installer? If yes, and you still have the error, consider asking at our support forum https://support.postsharp.net/ where you can upload your installer log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Visual Studio installation file, click the Modify button next to your installation, and then select the **.NET desktop development** option.

[image]

Hit Install and wait for it to finish modifying your installation.

When finished, re-run the PostSharp installer.